# Multi-platform deployment of a Firefox extension

Tags: c++, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

What is the right solution for multi-platform deployment of a Firefox extension which uses native c++ code? Is it possible to integrate all compiled binaries for different platforms in a single extension? Is it possible to download the only needed binaries (compiled from native c++ code) for the current machine?

Thanks.

Comment: Binary components are discontinued. You have to use js-ctypes, and will have to code for it per platform. As I do here: https://github.com/Noitidart/Profilist/blob/2.0/modules/workers/ProfilistWorker.js and here is blog entry talking about discontinued binary components: https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2015/05/04/dropping-support-for-binary-components/comment-page-1/

Comment: Some more examples of multi-platform js-ctypes: https://github.com/Noitidart/jscFileWatcher/blob/master/modules/workers/FSWatcherWorker.js and this one is simple doesnt have too much so you might like this one for reading: https://github.com/Noitidart/NativeShot/blob/master/modules/workers/MainWorker.js

Comment: @Noitidart Thanks for your reply. Maybe I am wrong. But, your provided links have no native c source code. As I mentioned, my native c code is already written (the c project is huge and for some reasons, it cannot be ported to JavaScript!). I think I should use 'js-ctypes' or 'system/child_process' to use a compiled shared library or a binary for the current platform. I wounder if there is a good solution to skip downloading irrelevant binaries and shared libraries which are for the other platforms. i.e, my main concern is the network traffic for downloading the Addon.

Comment: You might have trouble with the deprecation issue if you dont use js-ctypes. I have a situation where I need to use the native library so we are going to import the native file with jsctypes here: https://github.com/Noitidart/FoxSpeak/tree/master/modules

Comment: I would start out with child_process and see how far you get - at least you can start prototyping. js-ctypes are much more complex IMO.

Answer (score 2):

[Firefox is dropping support for binary components](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2015/05/04/dropping-support-for-binary-components/).  It says:

> Developers who rely on binary XPCOM should update their code as soon
>   as possible to prevent compatibility issues. If you have any questions
>   or comments about this move, please do so in the
>   [mozilla.dev.extensions](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mozilla.dev.extensions/B3H3j6FRVms) newsgroup.